# WindowKeyPressFcn executes after program interruption

Tags: matlab, callback

I want to detect pressing of the key, when running matlab script in while loop. At the moment, I only want to display `success`, after pressing of the key. Unfortunately, the message is displayed only after program interruption (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) not during program run. Here is the code:

```
% Init of callback
fig = gcf;
set(fig,'WindowKeyPressFcn',@keyPressCallback);


% keyPressCallback function
function keyPressCallback(source,eventdata)
    keyPressed = eventdata.Key;
    if strcmpi(keyPressed,'space')
        disp('success');
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to break the cycle of the script which is running so that Matlab will process other events, in essense your keypress.  You can do that by adding a drawnow inside you while loop, the code below should give you enough to incorporate in your own:

```
fig = figure;
set(fig,'WindowKeyPressFcn',@(hFig,hEvent)fprintf('pressed key %s\n',hFig.CurrentKey) );
drawnow();
while true
  if ~ishandle(fig); break; end
  drawnow();
end
```